# ¿Cómo añadir una columna calculada a un dataframe en r?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una función para calcular un score en función de determinadas estadísticas

```
scoring_p <- function(dataset,gls, xg,sh,sot,dri,aer,kp,xa){
  return (gls*2 + xg*2 + sh + sot + dri+ aer+ kp+xa)
}
```

y querría meter una columna nueva calculada con esa formula en el dataframe que tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: formato]

Pero no se muy bien como hacerlo, lo he intentado con apply pero no me salen los resultados esperables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los argumentos de la función se corresponden con valores de cada fila, ni siquiera necesitarías hacer una función, podrías resolverlo así:

```
data_p$NuevaColumna <- (data_p$`Gls.90` * 2) + (data_p$`XG.90` * 2)
```

No reproduzco completamente tu función, pero creo que la idea se entiende. Puedes evitar tener que nombrar el `data.frame` en cada referencia a una columna mediante:

```
with(data_p, 
     (`Gls.90` * 2) + (`XG.90` * 2)
)
```

Si aún así quieres usar `apply` deberías construir tu función de acuerdo a lo que `apply` le termina pasando, que no es más que un vector:

```
scoring_p <- function(x) {(x[1] * 2) + (x[2] *2)}

apply(data_p, 1, function(x) scoring_p(x))
```